# Solution Integro differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I try to solve the two integro differential equations

$f(at)=\frac{df(t)}{dt}$ and $f(at)=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)d\tau$   $a\gt0$.

Do you have an idea to suggest to me.

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{df(t)}{dt} = \int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau$$
Define $F(t):=\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau$, then
$$F''(t) =F(t)\tag{1}$$
the solution of $(1)$ is $F(t) = A\cdot e^t+B\cdot e^{-t})$

Then you deduce $f(t)$

Comment: @Gonçalo It's a typo. I corrected it

Comment: @ NN2 : Sorry, but there is a parameter in the first part of the equations : f(a*t). Thus I don't think that the F(t) you propose is a solution.

Comment: @user425269 We have
$$F''(t)=:\frac{df(t)}{dt} =f(at)=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)d\tau :=F(t)$$ right?

Comment: Dear NN2. No. In fact I have two different relation. The fault is mine. It would be better to write : how to solve:
$f(at)=\frac{df(t)}{dt}$ and $g(at)=\int_{0}^{t}g(\tau)d\tau$   $a\gt0$.

Comment: How to do that if now I have $f(at)=\frac{df(t)}{dt}$ and $g(at)=\int_{0}^{t}g(\tau)d\tau$   $a\gt0$.

Comment: @user425269 In this case, I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3452366/195378) than may answer your first equation. The second equation can be proved with similar method

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is a way to solve the problem.

Comment: @user425269 You're welcome!